# Access Denied When Launching VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to launch VSCode and I get the access denied error.

The error is pasted below. I can open the application only with `code --user-data-dir="./vscode-root"` but not sure if this is a good practice.

I also changed the permissions of `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/` to Read and Write.

Thanks in advance,
Lucy

```
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/lucijac/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/20180109T152903'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:895:18)
    at Function.sync (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at RotatingLogger (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/spdlog/index.js:13:11)
    at Object.t.createLogService (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:178:426)
    at q (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:407:340)
    at G (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:411:127)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:411:922)
    at Function.t._safeInvokeFunction (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:19:213)
    at Function.t._invokeFactory (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:19:460)
    at t.complete (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:19:731)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/Users/lucijac/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/20180109T152903' }
[main 15:29:03] Startup error: ,,,Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/lucijac/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/20180109T152903'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first line says it all, as also the last line:

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/lucijac/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/20180109T152903'`

It's unable to create this directory for the user you have logged in as. Check all the path permissions - are these directories created & owned by root/other user. It may not be a VS Code issue, it's likely to be a permissions issue.